# SSRS footer data based on groups

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I have this report which has a group based on a field "DeliveryNumber".

It works fine, after every new DeliveryNumber the report shows new data.

But now I want to do the same with the page footer. On every group the footer should show data belonging to just that deliverynumber.

Is this possible, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to show Delivery number in the page footer and you have only one Delivery Number per page(i.e. there is page break after every delivery number) then in page footer you can use `=ReportItems!Textbox1.Value`. (`Textbox1` in the expression is going to change, replace it with the textbox name in which you will keep the group header, that is Delivery Number field)

I hope this helps!